# MySQL: Optimizing Sub-queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

I have this query I need to optimize further since it requires too much cpu time and I can't seem to find any other way to write it more efficiently. Is there another way to write this without altering the tables?

```
SELECT category, b.fruit_name, u.name
, r.count_vote, r.text_c
FROM Fruits b, Customers u
, Categories c
, (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Reviews 
     ORDER BY fruit_id, count_vote DESC, r_id
   ) a 
   GROUP BY fruit_id
) r
WHERE b.fruit_id = r.fruit_id 
AND u.customer_id = r.customer_id 
AND category = "Fruits";
```

Comment: Your Categories table seems not joined/related  toe the others  ..  you have not a where condition for this table  ..  you should add  the related  tables schema a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Don't use comma-separated joins. They are prone to error, which is why explicit joins were introduced in standard SQL in 1992. This was before MySQL even got invented. You should dismiss your book / teacher / tutorial for teaching such ancient syntax.

Comment: How is the category table related to the other ones? To the fruit table? But why would a fruit ever belong to a category different from 'Fruits'? A customer on the other hand won't belong to a category called 'Fruits'. This looks weird somehow. Maybe you just over-simplified the sample query?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I did over-simplify it those are not the actual tables and fields but  rather a sample one

Comment: Although it is true, what led you to believe that your query was suboptimal? Have you used any profiling techniques? Refer https://aman-garg.medium.com/advanced-profiling-and-tracing-mysql-queries-c0c95dc7db24

If you know why your query is suboptimal, you'd know how to fix it too.

Comment: There are multiple `Reviews` for each `fruit_id`, correct?  Do you want to display all of them?  Or do you want just the one with the highest `count_vote`?  Your SQL fails to correctly do either.

Answer (score 0):

Your Categories table seems not joined/related  to the others  this produce a catesia product between all the rows

If you want distinct resut don't use group by  but distint so you can avoid an unnecessary subquery

and you dont' need   an order by on  a subquery

```
SELECT category
    , b.fruit_name
    , u.name
    , r.count_vote
    , r.text_c
FROM Fruits b
INNER JOIN  Customers u ON u.customer_id = r.customer_id
INNER JOIN  Categories c ON  ?????? /Your Categories table seems not joined/related  to the others  / 
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT distinct fruit_id, count_vote, text_c, customer_id
    FROM Reviews    
) r ON  b.fruit_id = r.fruit_id 
WHERE category = "Fruits";
```

for better reading you should use explicit join syntax  and avoid old join syntax based on comma separated tables name and where condition

Comment: this gives me an error code: unknown column though on "r.customer_id"...

Answer (score 0):

This is your query re-written with explicit joins:

```
SELECT 
  category, b.fruit_name, u.name, r.count_vote, r.text_c
FROM Fruits b
JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Reviews 
    ORDER BY fruit_id, count_vote DESC, r_id
  ) a 
  GROUP BY fruit_id
) r on r.fruit_id = b.fruit_id
JOIN Customers u ON u.customer_id = r.customer_id 
CROSS JOIN Categories c
WHERE c.category = 'Fruits';
```

(I am guessing here that the category column belongs to the categories table.)

There are some parts that look suspicious:

1. Why do you cross join the Categories table, when you don't even display a column of the table?
2. What is `ORDER BY fruit_id, count_vote DESC, r_id` supposed to do? Sub query results are considered unordered sets, so an `ORDER BY` is superfluous and can be ignored by the DBMS. What do you want to achieve here?
3. `SELECT * FROM [ revues ] GROUP BY fruit_id` is invalid. If you group by fruit_id, what count_vote and what r.text_c do you expect to get for the ID? You don't tell the DBMS (which would be something like `MAX(count_vote)` and MIN(r.text_c)`for instance. MySQL should through an error, but silently replaces`count_vote, r.text_c`by`ANY_VALUE(count_vote), ANY_VALUE(r.text_c)` instead. This means you get arbitrarily picked values for a fruit.

The answer hence to your question is: Don't try to speed it up, but fix it instead. (Maybe you want to place a new request showing the query and explaining what it is supposed to do, so people can help you with that.)

Comment: I meant to display c.category i just didn't put an alias ...

Comment: Okay, so I guessed right. What I was trying to say though is that you join categories rows without using them. The select list doesn't contain any categories column. I suppose the cross join is not intended, but I cannot be sure of course. Why is the categories table in your query? What's its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The next time you want help optimizing a query, please include the table/index structure, an indication of the cardinality of the indexes and the EXPLAIN plan for the query.

There appears to be *absolutely no reason for a single sub-query* here, let alone 2. Using sub-queries mostly prevents the DBMS optimizer from doing its job. So your biggest win will come from eliminating these sub-queries.

The CROSS JOIN creates a deliberate cartesian join - its also unclear if any attributes from this table are actually required for the result, if it is there to produce multiples of the same row in the output, or just an error.

The attribute `category` in the last line of your query is not attributed to any of the tables (but I suspect it comes from the categories table).

Further, your code uses a GROUP BY clause with no aggregation function. This will produce non-deterministic results and is a bug. Assuming that you are not exploiting a side-effect of that, the query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT 
  category, b.fruit_name, u.name, r.count_vote, r.text_c
FROM Fruits b
JOIN Reviews r 
ON r.fruit_id = b.fruit_id
JOIN Customers u ON u.customer_id = r.customer_id 
ORDER BY r.fruit_id, count_vote DESC, r_id;
```

Since there are no predicates other than joins in your query, there is no scope for further optimization beyond ensuring there are indexes on the join predicates.

As all too frequently, the biggest benefit may come from simply asking the question of why you need to retrieve every single row in the tables in a single query.